# UK -Obtained Certificate of Sponsorship Number, am I obliged to work for that company now?

Tags: united-kingdom, working-visas

I have recently obtained a CoS from a company, I have not yet signed any contracts with them, nor have I applied for the Tier 2 visa with them. Am I obliged to work for them now?

EDIT:

I have studied in UK for a very long while now and I have previously worked under Tier 2. At the moment, I am on Tier 4. And I am in UK.

Answer (score 2):

No. You can inform that company that you've changed your mind and there is not a thing they can do about. The Tier-2 visa is not a work contract with the company. It is a legal agreement between you and the government of the United Kingdom (it is likewise such for the company as well).

Comment: I am actually in UK atm. But on a student visa. Thanks

Comment: Would you mind updating your question? I will update my answer.